# Usage of COALESCE for no rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have used COALESCE numerous times but I suppose I never encountered this particular situation. Assume there is only one row per @param1.

```
select @test = COALESCE (column1, 'default') FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1
```

In this scenario, if the value of column1 is null, 'default' is selected when the sql statement actually returns a row. What if there are no matching records for @param1.

Lets say I want to always have a default value for @test. Is the following correct or is there another way?

`select @test = COALESCE( (select column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1), 'default').`

I presumed that, `select @test = COALESCE (column1, 'default') FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1`, will contain 'default' even if it did not return a row. Nope.

I suppose I can also check if @test is NULL afterwards and assign a default value as well.

Comment: `NULL` is unknown. An empty result = complete and utter absence of value. How many shoes do I have in my car? The answer is probably `NULL` (unless you are hiding in my garage), because you can't possibly know how many shoes are in my car -- assuming I have a car. If I don't have a car, the answer is not `NULL`, it's the empty set.

Comment: @aaron, I think this is one of the bad analogies I have heard so far today. :). I would think it is the other way around. If you have a car, then there is 0 or x number of shoes in that car. Its not NULL. but if you don't have a car at all, it is NULL because the source does not exist and that question is not valid.

Comment: it depends on the perspective. If I'm asking *you* how many shoes are in *my* car, can you really confidently say 0 or x? No, you can only answer "unknown." If I don't have a car, isn't it true that `SELECT * FROM car INNER JOIN shoe` returns an empty set, not `NULL` or `0`? You can't say the question is not valid, you've already run the query. SQL Server doesn't complain that your question wasn't valid, it just returns an empty set.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then. but if you tried to assign that #of shoes to a variable, that variable will be 'unknown', regardless of whether the qurey returned an empty set or 'unknown'.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1` can yield an empty set.  And yes, that means that `SELECT @var = column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1` never assigns a value to @var.  Yet, `SET @var = (SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1)` does assign `NULL` to @var.  The mechanism at play here is more to do with how SELECT works with assignment of values.  `SELECT @var = column1 FROM Table1` essentially assigns EVERY value to @var, though you only get to see the last assignment.  That's why `SELECT @total = @total + val FROM table` works in many cases.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to explain it logically, without bringing variable assignment into it - that's an implementation detail based on how you write your code and the fact that trying to assign an empty set, or assigning `NULL`, or never assigning a value at all, result in the exact same "value."

Comment: You can't assign a set to a scalar variable.  Thus implementation matters.  IMO :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You already effectively mentioned the answer...  Use `COALESCE` after/outside the SELECT, as otherwise you never actually assign a value (which is different from assigning a NULL value)...

```
SELECT @test = NULL
SELECT @test = column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1
SELECT @test = COALESCE(@test, 'default')
```

Or simply...

```
SELECT @test = COALESCE((SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column3 = @param1), 'default')
```

Comment: The second option you have is the same as what I have in my question, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could also just give the variable the default value at declaration. If no rows are returned by the query no assignment will be made.

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(10) = 'default'

SELECT  @test = COALESCE(column1, @test) /*Might not need COALESCE 
                                           if column1 is not nullable*/
FROM    Table1
WHERE   column3 = @param1 

SELECT  @test
```